# Google changed something in their maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im creating project with Google Maps API V3. Everything worked good but today, witchout changing code, maps crashed and wont run. Google changed something in their maps? I dont see anything. Console says nothing.

Comment: I just run my app working on Google maps V3. Everything works good.

Comment: I found Google Maps Forum and a lot of people have the same problem! Very strange, I can only wait. Thanks for reply, up arrow for you.

Comment: how did you conclude that google maps changed something today

Comment: On forums lot of people have exactly the same problem and my map worked yesterday, today is dead so thats not my fault

Comment: Do you have a link to live code? That would help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you specify a version in your URL for loading the google maps v3 script. If you do not, you will always be given the latest version (v3.9 now), and any code you have written against a previous version *could* break (but they're usually pretty good about backwards compatibility).

See [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) for more about using particular versions with Google Maps v3.